# choosing my join / conditional

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables 
one contains questions with a reused question list number, question number, and questions
the other contains answers and has question numbers, unique survey number, and answers
I am trying to combine these to identify missing answers.

q.qid and a.question are both question numbers

q.sid is a reused question list number

a.sid is the unique survey number

```
SELECT * FROM question q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.qid = a.question
WHERE q.sid=3 AND a.sid =2259
ORDER BY q.qid
```

problem is how we stand because of the where I am only asking for questions to appear that have answers assigned in survey id 2259.

BUT I want to list all questions from q.sid 3 and include the answers from a.sid = 2259 (but not a.sid 2260 or 2261... which use the same q.sid of 3)  and include a NULL value if there isn't an entry.

is this possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you move the relevant part of the WHERE condition into the JOIN condition, i.e. join only with rows with sid=2259.

```
SELECT *
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.qid=a.question AND s.sid=2259
WHERE q.sid=3
ORDER BY q.qid
```